# How to use a script to generate a table on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an SQL type file which is basically a script to generate a table for a database. I have created a database, and am administering it with phpMyAdmin. My question is, how do I use that script stored in my local storage, to generate a table on the database of my server, using phpMyAdmin. I am not experienced in using sql, and am a newbie in general programming. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You. [image]

Comment: the script is indeed a SQL command / a series of SQL commands. Store it as `.sql` format and import via `Import` function of phpMyAdmin. What is your exact question / problem ?

Answer (score 1):

go to "Import" panel (the link on the navigation bar) then click the "browse" button and select your script. Then click the "go" button (bottom right) and you should have your result.